# Backbone.Marionette CompositeView optionlist

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'd like to create a CompositeView that contains a dropdown-list from a collection:

my views:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#item-tpl'
});

var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#comp-tpl',
    itemView: ItemView,
    itemViewContainer: '#mySelect'         
});
```

my templates:

```
<script id = "item-tpl" type="text/template">
    <option value="<%= id %>"><%= name %></option>
</script>

<script id = "comp-tpl" type="text/template">
   ...
          <form>
          <div class="control-group">
                <select id='mySelect'></select>
          </div>
         </form>

   ...
</script>
```

the rendered HTML displays the default div's, which break the options list

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <div>
        <option value="5">name 1</option>
    </div>
    <div>
        <option value="6">name 2</option>
    </div>
</select>
```

how can I achieve this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="5">name 1</option>
    <option value="6">name 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Lrm/8/

Start by simplifying your template:

```
<script id = "item-tpl" type="text/template">
  <%= name %>
</script>
```

Then, you need to provide the information about the item view so it renders with the data you want:

```
var aItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#item-tpl',
    tagName: "option",
    onRender: function(){
        this.$el.attr('value', this.model.get('id'));
    }
});
```

You specify the `tagName` attribute so it doesn't get rendered with the default `div` tag but uses the `option` tag you need. Then, when the option gets rendered, you need to set the `value` attribute, which you do with the `onRender` function.

Finally, here's your new composite view:

```
var aCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#comp-tpl',
    itemView: aItemView,  
    itemViewContainer: "select"   
});
```

We specify the `itemViewContainer` to tell Marionette where to put our item views. That way, there's no need for us to redefine `appendHtml`.

This solution is a lot cleaner, since we're using Marionette functionality instead of doing everything on our own... But of course, the other solutions will work also.

If you want to learn more about generating the proper HTML structure with Marionette, you might be interested in this blog post of mine: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty easy actually the only thing you need to do is wrap the "el" (element) with **jquery** so the view should look like this:

```
var aItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
..
..

  el: $('#mySelect'),

..
```

that avoid the default div and you can use only the elements you need.
so will get this instead

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="5">name 1</option>
  <option value="6">name 2</option>
</select>
```